# DDD - Getting access to user email from different domains

Tags: domain-driven-design

Let's assume I was building a collaborative document editing platform ala Google Docs.

`Collaborators` work together on a `Document`. A `Collaborator` must be a user of the platform.

There's a `Comment` subdomain that allows `Collaborators` to communicate within a `Document`.

When a `Comment` is created, all `Collaborators` should be notified according to their account notification preferences (email, SMS or both).

The notification preferences is stored in a seperate `Users` domain.

How can I notify the users whilst maintaining clean separation of my domains?

The options I see:

- Raise a `CommentPosted` domain event from within the `Comment` domain and listen to the event within a `Comment` application service, which makes a call to the `User` domain for the users and then invokes the `EmailService` to send an email. The issue here is now the `Comment` application service knows about and is coupled on the `User` domain.
- Have the `User` service listen to the `CommentPosted` event. With event-carried state transfer the `User` service should have enough knowledge to formulate and send the email. Still, not sure that it's a good idea for the `User` service to know about `CommentPosted` event (then again, isn't that part of the idea behind an event-sourced system?).
- Still raise `CommentPosted` from within the `Comment` domain but this time have the handler fire off a `SendEmailCommand` message. Have an infrastructure email service (most likely a microservice) listen to the `SendEmailCommand`. The email service can then make a request to the `User` service to get the email (and probably have it's own cache of `UserId` to `Email` anyway).

  This seems to be the most generic approach but it does mean the Email infrastructure service now needs some understanding of domain constructs (namely, the `UserId`). Again, I'm not entirely sure that this is a bad thing.

  At the moment, the Email service is basically just a dumb `port` to an external email service with one method: `Email.sendEmail(Email email)`. In this case, it'll might need to change to `Email.sendEmail(User userId, Email email)`.

Comment: The events are the interface between your services. In dep. inversion terms, events *are* the abstraction. The services aren't coupled to each other, but to the event format/protocol, so design that carefully. Also, it's worth knowing that not all of the system has to use event sourcing. BTW, this seems like really a single domain with multiple services, so if you are in control of all of it, there's no need for internal anti-corruption layers. Consider too that notification preferences don't have to be stored in the User service, you could store them with the service that actually needs them.

Comment: I guess the design of events is part of my confusion. If the User service actually cared about the event it wouldn't be an issue, but in this case the only function of the event is to query the User for it's email and notification preference to enable the sending of the email. If anything it almost feels like a command in disguise.

Comment: The example I gave is simplified in the sense that more than one service cares about the notification preferences. Goes back to having the email or notification store or cache that info, but again, it feels weird to have to add a custom event handler in that service for each email that needs to be sent. In that scenario a Command seems to make more sense.